# NTFS permissions to allow a user to access and save to a folder, but not to delete or change contents?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I am in the process of trying different combinations of settings however in the process of learning. Could anybody point me in the right direction?
Many thanks

Comment: Please, avoid [opinion-based](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) questions, and try editing you question so it asks a more concise question ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many sources of information.  Start with those from Microsoft:

- [NTFS Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784990%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [How IT works: NTFS Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.11.howitworksntfs.aspx)

In your terms, "access" refers to

> List Folder Contents. Users can view a list of a folder's contents.

and "save to a folder"

> Write. Users can write to a file.

They need read-access anyway.  You want to *deny* these:

> ***Full Control***. Users can do anything to the file, including taking ownership of it. It is recommended that you grant this level of access only to administrators.
>
> ***Modify***. Users can view and modify files and file properties, including deleting and adding files to a directory or file properties to a file. Users cannot take ownership or change permissions on the file.

and can do this starting with the folder permissions, applying the result to subdirectories and their contents.